# Calling lambda from another lambda or exposing api through api-gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am contemplating if I should invoke lambda directly from another lambda or should I expose api through api-gateway in front of lambda. I am looking for pros and cons for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 Using API Gateway**

API Gateway and Lambda have one of the best integrations for serverless applications. It is very widely used and offers a ton of features - [proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), [mapping templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html), [custom domain names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) and different types of [authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html).

However, with these pros comes the cons due to some limits with using API Gateway. API Gateway has a default integration time out (a hard limit) of 29 seconds - which means the Lambda function needs to send back a response to API within this time frame or API fails with a 504 response. You may review other limits related to API Gateway [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

**Approach #2 Lambda invoking Lambda**

I'm not a big fan of this approach and have multiple reasons for it. I'll start with the additional code you have to write - same task with better features can be done by API Gateway with simple configurations on the AWS console.

A container calling another container(Lambda) can result it container-related problems - networking, container reuse and even managing IAM permissions properly.

Also, a Lambda function can be [invoked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-invocation.html) by only three options - SDK, CLI or an entity that has "Invoke" permission. So basically, you need to have some kind of resource in front of your first Lambda to invoke it which will then invoke the second. In my opinion, API Gateway is the best front-end you can have for Lambda which is exactly AWS had in mind building these two services.

One of the pros I can think of this approach is the time out value - Lambda can run for up to max of 15 mins. Unless your client does not require a response back pretty quickly, you can run these two Lambda functions for a longer time to execute code.

**Summary**

All the above information was pretty general for anyone looking to use API Gateway and Lambda. I'll say it again that using API Gateway is a more convenient and useful approach however it may depend on your use-case. Hope this helps!

Comment: W.r.t use cases, I have used a lambda to invoke another lambda to carry out entity caching (in S3/Elasticsearch) for example. Caching is an activity that may take more than 15 minutes (timeout for lambda function) so I can have a CloudWatch event attached to the trigger lambda that would invoke the other lambda on a time based schedule.

Comment: Yes I understand that lambda direct invocation has benefit of timeout of 15 minutes. I am working on usecase where response time is well within API gateway timeout. Considering that why approach would you advice

Comment: @sarupdalwani If your Lambda response is going to be within 29 seconds, you should consider using API Gateway.

Comment: @sarupdalwani if you're concerned about the extra latency that going through API Gateway would result in, that might be a reason to invoke directly. At my work we have internal service to service calls that need to happen to run business logic validations, for instance, and for these sorts of situations we've chosen to invoke directly instead of going out to the public internet where an API Gateway uri is exposed and then back into Lambda